How do I use the timer on vb.net 2022
I have school project where I has to code a simple program in vb.net, and I have chosen to make a sleep reminder app. I have the buttom and time picker sorted, but I don't know how to let vb.net know the time and set off the notification using the timer function on vb. Would be very grateful if someone coule help me.
I am aiming for a program that when you hit run, it will ask for the current time or even access the system time, and then detect if it is past 11 or so and give exponentially more and more reminders to turn off the system and 'go to sleep'.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGuy1blchEk

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer

The following post contains some information that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78536283/10024425 (under the heading "Add a Timer to Form1 ")

@topsail, a WinForms Timer would be more appropriate than a system Timer if, as is highly likely, this is a WinForms app`

There is no "timer function". Timer is a class. To be more specific, it is a component, which means that you can add one to your form in the designer, much like a control but without a UI. If you have actually researched the Timer class, as you should have, then you know that it has an Interval property that specifies when the Tick event is raised. You need to calculate that interval, based on the current time and the time you want it to tick.

@jmcilhinney - this is exactly what I was thinking - using the tick event (and yes would be necessary to calculate the interval based on the current time and the time you want it to tick). However, since it's a school project - I wanted the student to have a chance to work out as much on their own as possible, ideally from the documentation as that's a plus to learn how to use the official docs to explore .NET. In any case, nowhere in my comment (which is only a link to the documentation) do I mention a "timer function" or claim that one exists in the Timer class.

@topsail, my second comment, including reference to a "timer function", was directed at the OP, because that's what they said in the question. My comment directed at you was just a single sentence, re the type of Timer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
